# access Help Scout threads content through the API

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to access to the body of each threads on a conversacion of Help Scout via the  Mailbox API 2.0

I am using this library:  https://pypi.org/project/python-helpscout-v2/

And I can access the conversations by email doing:

```
from helpscout import HelpScout

_id='my_id'
_secret='my_secret'

hs = HelpScout(app_id=_id, app_secret=_secret)

email= the_email
params = 'query=(email:"'+email+'")&status=all' 
conversations = hs.conversations.get(params=params)
```

How Can I do it?

The link of the threads is on the conversation._links['threads']['href']

and I get something like:

```
https://api.helpscout.net/v2/conversations/a_number/threads/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it now.

For example, if I want to access to the threads of the first conversation of an user, I can do:

```
from helpscout import HelpScout

_id='my_id'
_secret='my_secret'

hs = HelpScout(app_id=_id, app_secret=_secret)

email= the_email
params = 'query=(email:"'+email+'")&status=all' 
conversations = hs.conversations.get(params=params)


dic = conversations[0]

threads = dic._links['threads']['href']           
threads = hs.hit(threads, 'get')
```

So threads will be a generator and then I can iterate over it.